# Server crash due performance issues on my NestJs Graphql Prisma

Tags: server, graphql, nestjs, backend, prisma

I am asking my question here, cause I've read a lot of documentation about it and applying it but it still not working.

I am building a Graphql API on NestJS using Prisma as ORM
The problem is when I do big queries, but server crashes without any log or anything, I just can't reach it after this.
Example of query not working

```
query DepositsList($organizationId: String!) {
depositsList(filter: {organizationId: {equals: $organizationId}}) {
    id
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    organizationId
    userId
    user {
        id
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        email
        phone
        lastname
        firstname
        avatarURL
    }
    articles {
        id
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        depositId
        saleId
        type
        ean
        brand
        depositPrice
        marginRate
        salesRate
    }
    organization {
        id
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        name
        baseMarginRate
    }
}
```

}

Example of query working

```
query DepositsList($organizationId: String!) {
depositsList(filter: {organizationId: {equals: $organizationId}}) {
    id
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    organizationId
    userId
    user {
        id
        email
        lastname
        firstname
    }
    articles {
        id
        depositId
        saleId
        type
        ean
        brand
        depositPrice
        marginRate
        salesRate
    }
}
```

}

I've seen documentation about prisma performance issues, which I think I am applying. ie: with the `prisma.deposit.findUnique({where: {id}}).articles()`

Here is a part of my code:
`deposit.resolver.ts`

```
@Resolver(() => Deposit)
export class DepositResolver {
    constructor(
        private readonly depositService: DepositService,
        private readonly organizationService: OrganizationService,
        private readonly articleService: ArticleService,
        private readonly userService: UserService
    ) {}
@Query(() => Deposit, { description: "Get a deposit by id" })
async deposit(
    @Args("id", { type: () => String, nullable: true }) id: string
): Promise<Deposit> {
    return await this.depositService.getDepositById(id);
}

@Query(() => [Deposit], { description: "Get deposits by filter" })
async depositsList(
    @Args("filter", { nullable: true }) filter: DepositWhereInput,
    @Args("limit", { nullable: true }) limit: number,
    @Args("skip", { nullable: true }) skip: number,
    @Args("orderBy", { nullable: true })
    orderBy: DepositOrderByWithRelationInput
): Promise<Deposit[]> {
    return await this.depositService.getDeposits(filter, limit, skip, orderBy);
}

@Mutation(() => Deposit, { description: "Create a deposit" })
async createDeposit(
    @Args("data") data: DepositCreateInput
): Promise<Deposit> {
    return await this.depositService.createDeposit(data);
}

@ResolveField("organization", () => Organization)
async organization(@Parent() deposit: Deposit): Promise<Organization> {
    const { id: depositId } = deposit;
    return await this.organizationService.getOrganizationByDepositId(depositId);
}

@ResolveField("user", () => User)
async user(@Parent() deposit: Deposit): Promise<User> {
    const { id: depositId } = deposit;
    return await this.userService.getUserByDepositId(depositId);
}

@ResolveField("articles", () => [Article])
async articles(@Parent() deposit: Deposit): Promise<Article[]> {
    const { id: depositId } = deposit;
    return await this.articleService.getArticlesByDepositId(depositId);
}
```

}

And `article.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {
    constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

    async getArticleById(id: string): Promise<Article> {
        return await this.prisma.article.findFirstOrThrow({
            where: {
                id: id,
            },
        });
    }

    async getArticlesByDepositId(depositId: string): Promise<Article[]> {
        return await this.prisma.deposit
            .findUnique({ where: { id: depositId } })
            .articles();
    }
}
```

A part of my `user.service.ts`

```
async getUserByDepositId(depositId: string): Promise<User> {
    return await this.prisma.deposit
        .findUnique({ where: { id: depositId } })
        .user();
}
```

A part of my `organization.service.ts`

```
async getOrganizationByDepositId(depositId: string): Promise<Organization> {
    return await this.prisma.deposit
        .findUnique({ where: { id: depositId } })
        .organization();
        
}
```

Does anyone knows why it's crashing my server ? The doc I've read seems to do exactly how I do.
Thanks a lot for your time !